# programmatically load viewController class

Tags: ios, swift, segue, uistoryboardsegue

I want to load show (segue to) specific ViewController class when a user click a button.

I need to do it only in code without dragging and creating segues in the story board.

Say i have root viewController:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

func startPlayer(sender: AnyObject) {

    // B.startView()  // should segue to ViewController B
}
```

The second viewController:

```
class B:ViewController
{
   class func startView()
   {
      // Load this viewController and show it on screen (force segue to it) 

   }}
```

I am writing sort of framework and need it to happen automatically and can't make the user drag and create segue from story board

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can initiate nextview programetically this way:

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("someViewController") as! UIViewController
self.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("someViewController") require to define a segue with this identifier? how is someViewController defined?

Comment: You need to assign storyBoard ID to next view controller.